# Traefik backend.loadbalancer.swarm or not

Tags: load-balancing, docker-swarm, traefik

The tag `traefik.backend.loadbalancer.swarm` is default to false with `--docker.swarmMode`, however I wanted to know if there is any advantages / disadvantages to turn it on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've gathered so far, `traefik.backend.loadbalancer.swarm` with cause traefik to call the backend service (by a virtual ip) via the swarm mesh routing network, resulting a single backend record in the dashboard.

#### Advantage

Not sure, they both use round robin by default.

#### Disadvantage

Lose the following features:

- wighted round robin
- sticky session as swarm lb doesn't have it natively right now